# Find all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2i\\
    -3i&-4\end{pmatrix}$$
I got $λ^2 - 3λ - 4 + 6i^2 = 0$

-I isoloated down to $i^2 = -1/6 (λ -4)(λ+1)$ and wrote how λ must be -1 < λ < 4.  I don't know what to do next

Comment: Do you know that $i^2=-1$? That’ll give you a polynomial $\lambda^2 -3\lambda -10=0$ which I assume you can solve.

Comment: For future reference, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) gives information on how to type mathematical equations and such on this site using MathJax and $\LaTeX$, making your posts much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fact that $i^2=-1$ within your determinate of the matrix. Furthermore it should be $+3\lambda$ instead of $-3\lambda$. Therefore you got $\lambda^2+3\lambda-4+6(-1)=0$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: You are welcome. Just accept the answer to show that you are satisfied with the answers to your post :)

Answer (score 1):

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2i\\
    -3i&-4\end{pmatrix}$$
Now $|A-\lambda I|=0$
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda & 2i \\ -3i & -4-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=0$$
$$(1-\lambda)(-4-\lambda)+6i^2=0$$
$$-4-\lambda+4\lambda+\lambda^2-6=0$$
$$\lambda^2+3\lambda-10=0$$
$$(\lambda+5)(\lambda-2)$$
$$\lambda=-5,2$$

To find the eigenvector you need to find the null space using the above eigen values